Create transposed summary
I have a table starting from Column A in row 5:
table_number   name
 1             cathy
 3             sarah
 1             bob
               jake     (no table allocated so can ignore)

On a new sheet, how could I transform it so I can see it alphabetically in numerical order. (If two identical names are allocated to the same table, the name should show twice i.e. allow duplicates):
1        2        3
bob      ...     sarah
cathy



You may try:
=map(torow(sequence(max(A5:A))),lambda(Σ,ifna(vstack(Σ,sort(filter(B:B,A:A=Σ))))))



how could I update this pls, so that it starts from the minimum value in Column A? (rather than always starting from 1)

try with =sequence(max(A5:A)-min(A5:A)+1,1,min(A5:A)) in place of sequence(max(A5:A))

lastly sorry, is there a way to limit it to the values in column A e.g if col A is from 15 to 35 but has no 19, 19 should be ignored

=sort(unique(tocol(A5:A,1)))

what would be the formula to do the reverse - i.e. go from the expected output to the input, please?

or simply pivot it:
=QUERY(A1:B4, "select min(B) where A is not null group by B pivot A")



nicer:
=INDEX(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(A:B, 
 "select min(B) where A is not null group by B pivot A"),,8^8)), " ")))


